# How to xtract JwtSecurityToken payload into string or dictionary?

Tags: c#, jwt, payload

I am trying to write code that decodes a given encrypted JSON, and extracts it into a string or dictionary.
My original json is:
`{"attributes":{},"ttl":0,"userId":"user1@gmail.com"}`

```
string signature = jsonNode["token"].ToString();
var token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(signature);
```

The token displays the correct payload as 3 items, but I don't find how to get these values and use them easily.
I find:
`token.Payload.Values` which returns the values only, or `token.Payload.Keys` which returns the keys only.
No `token.Payload.Items` to return both keys and values, and no way to get it as JSON string (something like `{"attributes":{},"ttl":0,"userId":"user1@gmail.com"}`.

I believe it's a very basic operation, but google it lot of times and didn't find a solution.

I am using jwt 6.27

Answer (score 1):

[`JwtSecurityToken.Payload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytoken.payload?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest) property is of type [`JwtPayload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtpayload?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest) which is `Dictionary<string,object>`, so you can use indexer, for example:

```cs
var userId = token.Payload["userId"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good workaround. but isn't there a more elegant option? in this case it's not so bad to take manually 3 attributes, but let's say that json include 10 attributes?

Comment: @Riki you can try using `RawPayload` and deserializing it to some model class, but I have not tried that.